# c# - WriteLine overlap

Tags: c#, algorithm, loops, printing

Is it possible to write a loop that will write to the console with overlapping text?

Desired output:

[image: over]

Notice how the lines overlap. I was using '|' vertically and '-' horizontally.

The vertical line is the 4th column and the horizontal line is the 3rd row.

I know this is way off:

```
 for (int i = 1; i <= 4; i++)
            {
                Console.Write("    |   ");
                for (int x = 1; x <= 6; x++)
                {
                    Console.Write("    -   ");
                }
            }
```

Comment: What character do you want to use for the intersection? "+" possibly?

Comment: I was wondering if I could do it without the '+', is there anyway that '|' and '-' can overlap?

Comment: In a console, each "slot" can only have a single character. So you need to decide which character you want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try [Extended ASCII Codes](http://www.asciitable.com/). These might help you draw pretty pseudographics:

```
╒╥╦╫
```

Comment: Does literally provide the only answer which is valid, I ended up using '+' though.